# Set Button caption to resource string from dialog designer in VC++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, atl, wtl

I know it may seem a silly question but I've been searching for days.

How to - if that's even possible - set, from Visual Studio's Resource Editor a Button's caption to a Resource String?
I am aware that that's pretty easy to do by code, but how to do that at design time?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. Why do you want to?

Comment: No you can't. If you want to set the string at design time, set it directly in the dialog resource.

Comment: I was just wondering if that was possible. Linking caption to resource strings via the Dialog editor. Thanks though.

Comment: @FrancisStraccia no, it is not possible. Resource dialogs simply do not work that way. You can put a static string in a resource dialog, and the localize the entire dialog. But if you want a resource string to appear in a UI, you have to load the string at runtime and assign it to the desired UI control.